# Image styles based on node type

Tags: 7, nodes, media

Let's say i have two node types:

- `Article` - with `300x300` photo
- `News` - with `100x100` photo

For now, i can define those two sizes in Image Styles menu and they'll be both created for both content types (so both `Article` and `News` will have two images generated - in size `300x300` and `100x100`).

My question is - is there any way to set which content type shoud use which image style(s) ? **Please note that i'm not interested in generating both of them and displaying just one. It would kill my server and my wallet (i'm using Amazon s3).** Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think there is no way

Comment: Does the setting on the content type's field display settings page not do this? I thought Drupal only generates styles when they're used somewhere.

Comment: I dont think an image is generated using Image Styles Until it is called the first time to display in a page.

Comment: Derivative images won't be created until they are explicitly made to do so through code, or the style URL is requested. As long as you don't request the paths for the image styles you don't want to exist, they won't get created

Comment: oh right, i had no idea it works this way. Thank you for your help, please post this solution as a reply so i could mark it as accepted :)

Comment: ditto what Clive commented, but 300x300 and especially 100x100 images are going to be pretty inexpensive to host (amazon get requests notwithstanding), so, I'd look into the original file sizes as that's where some cost might be, and make sure they are reasonable in maximum original size as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting on the content type's field display settings page allows you to choose image style to display. Drupal only generates styles when they're used somewhere.